# Ethernet not working ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, internet, ethernet

I can't get my device connected to the internet.

This is the content of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface usb0 inet dhcp

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

When I try "ifup eth0", I get:

```
no DHCPOFFERS received
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    ifconfig -a
dummy0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2e:0e:d3:d4:b1:2e  
          BROADCAST NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:4b:21:2f:b9  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ip6tnl0   Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      NOARP  MTU:1452  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:560 (560.0 B)  TX bytes:560 (560.0 B)

rmnetctl  Link encap:IPIP Tunnel  HWaddr   
      NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
      NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 1):

The interfaces files appears wrong. There should be a `auto eth0` above the line `iface eth0 inet dhcp`.

The same applies for the other network interfaces as well.

Comment: didn't work also and rebooting took a lot of time trying to configure without success.

Comment: because of the errors in the interfaces file, the system is trying to establish a connection and it tries this for exactly 2 minutes. Then it boots in without any network connections. For the sake of testing, please comment out the usb0 and wlan0 lines by putting a `#` in the starting of the line and do a system reboot.

Comment: Added 'auto eth0' and commented the other lines but still no internet.

Comment: Ok. Let's try to debug. Please post the output of `ifconfig -a`

Comment: I updated the question with the output.

Comment: Well, you system is not receiving an IP from the DHCP server/router. Can you please check for possibility of a faulty network cable or router configuration?

Comment: Well it is actually a zte usb modem with acts as ethernet. It is working fine on other devices.

Comment: zte USB modem is not ethernet. I would suggest to configure the modem via the network-manager instead of modifying the interfaces files. You would encounter a wizard and you can follow the steps to set up internet connection.

Comment: tried this before. It is seen as wired connection.